# Change the alpha value of a pixel

Tags: java, image, hex, pixel, transparent

I am trying to change the alpha value of a pixel to make a image half transparent. Here is my code:

```
for(int x=0;x<image1.getWidth();x++) {
    for(int y=0;y<image1.getHeight();y++) {
        int rgb = image1.getRGB(x, y);

        rgb = rgb | 0x000000ff; // make the image blue.
        rgb = rgb & 0x33ffffff; // make the image transparent.
        System.out.println("before: " + Integer.toHexString(rgb));

        image1.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
        int now_rgb= image1.getRGB(x, y);
        System.out.println("after: " + Integer.toHexString(now_rgb));
    }
}
```

The output is something like that:

```
before: 331b1aff
after: ff1b1aff
before: 331918ff
after: ff1918ff
before: 331e1bff
after: ff1e1bff
before: 332623ff
after: ff2623ff
before: 332e29ff
after: ff2e29ff
```

As you can see, its seems like the setRGB omitted the alpha value and set it to "ff". How can I resolve this problem, and why does it happen in the first place?

Comment: Depending on how attached to the current process you are, you could have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054596/change-color-of-non-transparent-parts-of-png-in-java/16054956#16054956)

Comment: Try to print image1.getType(), it should be ARGB. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because your `BufferedImage`'s color model does not support alpha or possibly only uses a single bit for alpha.

Where did you get `image` from?  Is its color model also ARGB?  Use `image.getColorModel().`[hasAlpha()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html#hasAlpha%28%29) to check.  If not, make sure when you create your image it has an appropriate color model, and if it can't be changed, create a new image with the desired color model and copy the source image first.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [AlphaComposite](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html):

```
BufferedImage img = //some code here
BufferedImage imgClone = //some clone of img, but let its type be BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
Graphics2D imgCloneG = imgClone.createGraphics();
imgCloneG.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.DST_IN, 0.5f));
imgCloneG.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
//imgClone is now img at half alpha
```

`imgClone` can be made like this:

```
...
imgClone = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), 
                             BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D imgCloneG = imgClone.createGraphics();
imgCloneG.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
imgCloneG.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.DST_IN, 0.5f));
...
```